# How to retrieve data from firebase properly with a url in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I am trying to retrieve data from my firebase realtime database but I am stuck on the following code how to approach it properly. I have a tableview list of categories where when the select of the certain category, I want to show that particular data which is `data` key value from database onto the view. Is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
struct DailyData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let model: String
    let text: String
}

extension DailyData {
    static func all() -> [DailyData] {
        return [
            DailyData(name: "Beginning", model: "", text: ""),
            DailyData(name: "Midnight Time", model: "Matins", text: ""),
            DailyData(name: "Morning Time", model: "Lauds", text: ""),
            DailyData(name: "Sunrise Time", model: "Prime", text: ""),
            DailyData(name: "Third Hour", model: "Terce", text: ""),
            DailyData(name: "Sixth Hour", model: "Sext", text: ""),
            DailyData(name: "Ninth Hour", model: "None", text: ""),
            DailyData(name: "Evening Time", model: "Vespers", text: ""),
            DailyData(name: "Peace Time", model: "", text: ""),
            DailyData(name: "Night Time", model: "Compline", text: ""),
        ]
    }
}
```

Firebase call:

```
struct LiturgyData: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var data: String
    
}
```

```
public class LiturgyFetcher: ObservableObject {

   @Published var sermons = [LiturgyData]()

    init(){
        load()
    }

    func load() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://MYPRIVATEURL.firebaseio.com/liturgyOfHours/.json")!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,error) in
            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode([LiturgyData].self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("finished getting services")
                        self.sermons = decodedLists
                    }
                }else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
            } catch {
                print ("Error")
            }

        }.resume()

    }
}
```

JSON Result from URL:

```
[
    {
        "data": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
        "id": 0,
        "title": "Beginning"
    },
    {
        "data": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Morning Time (Lauds)"
    }
     
]
```

View:

```
struct DailyWorshipView: View {
    @State private var model = DailyData.all()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(model) { dailydata in

                    LiturgyCell(dailydata: dailydata)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Hours"))
        }
    }

    #if DEBUG
    struct DailyWorshipView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            DailyWorshipView()
        }
    }
    #endif
    struct LiturgyCell: View {
        let dailydata: DailyData

        var body: some View {
            NavigationLink(destination: LiturgyDetail(liturgy: dailydata)) {
                HStack {
                    Text(dailydata.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: not getting the key value "data" when I select the category to show that data keys value onto my view.

Comment: Could you add the code of your *view* as well?

Comment: I added the view

Comment: @Vince *I have a tableview list of categories* - where is it?

Comment: please see updated code

Comment: Where and how are you merging your categories with the downloaded data?

Comment: the categories as of now is hardcode as you see from my first code above. and I am getting the data via with the url in `LiturgyFetcher` file above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide enough information, however, I think this might help you.

First, you need to add `LiturgyFetcher` to your `DailyWorshipView`:

```
@ObservedObject var liturgyFetcher = LiturgyFetcher()
```

Then you need a way to join `DailyData` with `LiturgyData`:

```
struct DailyData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let model: String
    let text: String
    
    // this is just the idea...
    var title: String {
        !model.isEmpty ? "\(name) (\(model))" : name
    }
}
```

and filter `liturgyFetcher.sermons` variable to find your liturgy:

```
liturgyFetcher.sermons.first{ $0.title == dailydata.title }
```

Your `DailyWorshipView` may look like this (you may want to move *filtering* to the `LiturgyFetcher`):

```
struct DailyWorshipView: View {
    @State private var model = DailyData.all()
    @ObservedObject var liturgyFetcher = LiturgyFetcher()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(model) { dailydata in
                    self.liturgyCell(dailydata: dailydata)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Hours"))
        }
    }
    
    func liturgyCell(dailydata: DailyData) -> some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: LiturgyDetail(liturgy: liturgyFetcher.sermons.first{ $0.title == dailydata.title })) {
            HStack {
                Text(dailydata.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use `LiturgyData` in your `LiturgyDetail` view as desired:

```
struct LiturgyDetail: View {
    let liturgy: LiturgyData?

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(liturgy?.title ?? "no liturgy found")")
    }
}
```

Comment: `liturgyFetcher.sermons.first{ $0.title == dailydata.title }` will be going inside the json call right?

Comment: @Vince Currently in my code it's in `DailyWorshipView`. You may want to add another method in your LiturgyFetcher to get specific LiturgyData but it will work with the current code as well. Just take a look at my version of `DailyWorshipView` - the code you mentioned is in the NavigationLink.

Comment: Thank you. I will test your code out soon and let you know if it works or not. thank you!

Comment: also, it works. but how can I make the view scrollable if the text is long ?

Comment: @Vince Please add another question if this one is answered. I'll be happy to help you there.